# Ipadm:operation failed

Tags: solaris

I am studying Solaris 11 in Virtualbox (64bit). I want to create network interface with command:

```
ipadm create-ip net3
```

But terminal says that

```
ipadm:cannot create interface net3:Operation failed
```

I stuck at this moment.Where is the problem?

EDIT: I am already root. maybe virtualbox is causing this problem?

Comment: And you have root access?

Comment: Please add more data. Please also note that questions about non-professional use of Solaris may be off-topic here (StackExchange has Unix.SE).

Comment: I don't know about it. Whatever, thanks for attention

Comment: @nuraureum that kind of behaviour is not very welcome. you ask for help and did not provide more info, probably you are even running the command as root since by default, user root in solaris 11 is a role and you need to use su or sudo to go to root.

Comment: @Alexandre Alves I am root. Maybe virtualbox causes problem?

Comment: Can you elaborate about what exactly you are trying to achieve ? How many NICs are configured for your VM on VirtualBox ? How is the fourth one configured (NAT, Bridge, ...) ?

Comment: I simply want to create network interface. One NIC is configured and it is NAT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably using an automatic network profile. If it is the case, many `ipadm` commands won't work by design.

You can switch to a fixed IP network profile with this command:

```
  netadm enable -p ncp defaultfixed
```

Reference: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1458/gljtt.html

Edit:

You only have one NIC configured in virtual box so there is no net3 to start with.

On non virtualized hardware, you could create a vnic that share the same physical interface as net0:

```
dladm create-vnic -t -l net0 vnic0
ipadm create-ip vnic0
```

However, as you are running on virtualized hardware, the networking emulation would likely be confused by the extra mac address so your best bet is to enable the fourth interface in your VM configuration in order to have net3 available.

Comment: thanks, but this method doesn't fix problem

Comment: What says `dladm show-link` ? Are there four NICs configured in VirtualBox for this VM ?

Comment: **LINK** **CLASS** **MTU** **STATE** **OVER**                                                              net0 phys 1500 up --                            (sorry i can't format as it is shown)

Answer (score 0):

the reason behind is that the interface is already used , you can not create